# Selection of fastest speed grade of Zynq in Vivado

Tags: vivado, zynq

I would like to make an implementation in Vivado using a Zynq z7030. I see that there are about 32 possible zynq's available. I would like to know which one of them is the fastest (if that can be said in generally). I suppose that the fastest ones are the ones ending on -3 but still then I have as options 
xc7z030fbv484-3, xc7z030fbv676-3, xc7z030ffg676-3, xc7z030ffv676-3 and so  on. Which one of them will be the fastest or do I have to simulate all of them in order to know that?

Kind regards

Comment: Did you look at the datasheet what all the different numbers mean? Many have to do with packaging which rarely affects your operating speed (unless you have to do a lot of I/O)

Comment: Agree, see datasheet

Answer (score 0):

- xc7z030fbv484-3,
- xc7z030fbv676-3,
- xc7z030ffg676-3,
- xc7z030ffv676-3

Usually **-3** (pronounced as **Dash 3 device**) devices are faster and premium cost too!!.Each speed grade will have different number of IO pins variation, if u look at the 484,676 they are denoting the number of IO pins available in the device and for the user usually will get the 65% of the mentioned pins remaining pins will be for power(vcc/gnd) and some dedicated pins like mode pins,jtag pins,done,program_b pins. Based on the user requirement for the IOs in the design u can select the device .. But as the IO count increases the device cost also increases.

> fbv,ffg,ffv

these are the package types of the devices. User can go through the family [data sheet](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds190-Zynq-7000-Overview.pdf)(23rd page) and can understand which type package user required.